# disable an element completely including links calling other javascript functions on click action

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class=" active">
<input class="check-shopby" type="checkbox" onclick="$(this).next().click()" checked="checked">
    <a class="checked" href="http://mysite/~dev433/products//cooking/cook-tops.html" onclick="$(this).previous().checked = false;" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <img width="150" alt="" src="site/media/wysiwyg/attribute_Sets_images/Fagor-CE9-20-1.jpg">
        <span> Electricity (74) </span>
    </a>
    <a onclick="otherjavascriptfunction" href="/somewhere">link</a>
</li>
```

Ok, this is my content inside a li item, when i go under certain condition i want it(the li item itself and all other clickable items inside) to be completely unclickable, if even possible some non-clickable(disabled) sign.

This is what i tried but it replaces my content, `$("div li a").replaceWith(function() {  return $(this).text(); });`

Comment: _when i go under certain condition_ - What condition and when this will be checked?

Comment: condition is i'm counting all the checkboxes. on remaining last item i don't allow user to click the last item.

Comment: Provide the whole event if possible as I said when you want to check this condition?

Comment: You can use `pointer-events: none;` on all link elements and to disable whole `li`, add a class to `li` with some opacity.

Answer (score 2):

You can add clickEventListener that will be listening on `li` element in captureMode

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate
>   capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTargets beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture.

```
var disableClicks = document.getElementsByClassName("disable-inner-clicks");
disableClicks.forEach(function(element){
   element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
   }, true);
});
```

Then for any element you want to disable clicks, just add `class = disable-inner-clicks`

```
<li class="active disable-inner-clicks">
  ....
</li>
```

No matter what content inside, clicks are disabled, and when your condition is fulfilled you just add the class to the element

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution. Set all children disabled and remove the click event.

```
$('li.active *').prop('disabled', true).off('click');
```

Comment: didn't seem working here, rather than this @patel comment above `pointer-events: none;` looks working for now